# An online wallets that sends transaction change back to the original address

Tags: wallet, change, paper-wallet

Is there any wallet client that conforms to the following:

- The wallet client is accessed through a website (for portability).
- The wallet client does not store any private keys (I know there is some trust involve). I want to access coins by providing a private key only, not by creating an account on the website.
- Most importantly, all the transaction change is to be payed to the original address. I do not want any additional addresses created during a transaction. I want to keep it as idiot-proof as possible and not rely on myself to keep track of any additional addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the client to generate any private keys for you, it seems what you need is a javascript client that builds and propogates transactions.

http://brainwallet.org/#tx

This is a hosted javascript client (everything happens on the client side so there is no security concerns) allows you to provide a private key and build a transaction that way.

Comment: This is exactly what you want. The best thing about this is you don't even send your private key, so it stays (moderately) safe in your computer! You can even [download it](https://github.com/brainwallet/brainwallet.github.com/archive/master.zip) and use it in an safe offline machine, copy the raw transaction and send it from your online machine.

Answer (score 0):

The closest service to what you speak of is https://easywallet.org. That i am aware of anyway.

It is run by the same good folk who run localbitcoins so its a trustworthy service.

Remember there are always risks with low security wallets and services such as this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. According to the site "about 1 percent monthly storage fee applies", which means they have access to my bitcoin. I want a service that only serves as an access point to my bitcoin by using my private key, without them storing my private key.

Comment: Basically you want a hosted JavaScript client which just does transactions but doesn't generate keys.. Nothing like this exists directly I doubt but you could probably modify blockchain.info to do this as it is open source..

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Blockchain's Wallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet/)?
I think it claims to operate in exactly the way you describe.